# Issues processing JSON API response

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to process the results of this API in Python:

https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets/BTC/12

When I assign the results of the API call to a variable I cannot seem to iterate over it or even call objects in it. When I do something like `response[0]` I'm only getting single characters. I need to be able to get to the "Data" object in there and iterate over it.

I'm stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've never used Python but it seems like you're accessing the string instead of a JSON object, have you checked the Python docs, https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html, on decoding JSON responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are retrieving the data from the API, but I would reccomend using the Python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

You would send off the request:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets/BTC/12')
```

From there you want JSON data back, so convert the data to JSON like so:

`data = r.json()`

Then you can just parse the attributes you want from the API. If you wanted the `label` attribute for the 1st object in the `Data` array, you would do something like this:

```
>>> data['Data'][0]['Label']
>>> '$$$/BTC'
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked. I was trying it with json.loads() and it was not working. Using r.json() worked and now I can maneuver around. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sequenzia: You should call `json.loads()` on the response content, not the response object. `json.loads(r.content)` should also work, but `r.json()` is clearly better.

Comment: Thanks @mhawke that makes sense also.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much detail, however, you probably need to decode the JSON response. Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module for that. Something like this should help, but it depends on what the actual response is:

```
import json

data = json.loads(response)
print(data['Data'][0])
```

**Output**

```
{'TradePairId': 1261, 'Label': '$$$/BTC', 'AskPrice': 7.5e-07, 'BidPrice': 7.2e-07, 'Low': 7.1e-07, 'High': 7.5e-07, 'Volume': 92820.5864058, 'LastPrice': 7.3e-07, 'BuyVolume': 52598028.48552139, 'SellVolume': 7797125.25042393, 'Change': 2.82, 'Open': 7.1e-07, 'Close': 7.3e-07, 'BaseVolume': 0.06782329, 'BuyBaseVolume': 1.87597261, 'SellBaseVolume': 173448022.5864104}
```

In this case `json.loads()` returns a dictionary, and the actual data is the value of the `Data` key which is a list of dictionaries. To iterate over the dictionaries:

```
for d in data['Data']:
    print(d)
```

If you are using the `requests` module to retrieve the data you can simply use the `json` method of the response to access the decoded data.